# Pandas collapse columns into a single column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking for a way to collapse multiple columns into a new single column.  Given the below data I'd like to create a new column called "Day" and populate they day value if available.  If a day is not populated I want to return the value of None. Can you help me accomplish this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Monday': {0: 'Monday', 1: 'None', 2: 'None'},
                   'Tuesday': {0: 'None', 1: 'None', 2: 'Tuesday'},
                   'Wednesday': {0: 'None', 1: 'None', 2: 'None'}})
```

DataFrame

```
   Monday  Tuesday Wednesday
0  Monday     None      None
1    None     None      None
2    None  Tuesday      None
```

New column with desired output:

```
        Day
0    Monday
1      None
2   Tuesday
```

I tried to use melt but does not accomplish exactly what I am looking for and creates extra rows for each column being collapsed.

My attempt:

```
df = pd.melt(df, var_name='Day')

          Day    value
0      Monday   Monday
1      Monday     None
2      Monday     None
3      Monday     None
4     Tuesday     None
5     Tuesday     None
6     Tuesday  Tuesday
7     Tuesday     None
8   Wednesday     None
9   Wednesday     None
10  Wednesday     None
11  Wednesday     None
```

Comment: Going with your direction : df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Day': pd.melt(df,var_name='day')['value'].unique()})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If need only first non missing value per rows first replace strings `None`s to missing values `NaN`, then back filling missing values and select first column by position:

```
df = df.replace('None', np.nan).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (df)
0     Monday
1        NaN
2    Tuesday
3        NaN
Name: Monday, dtype: object
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.replace('None', np.nan))
   Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday
0  Monday      NaN        NaN
1     NaN      NaN        NaN
2     NaN  Tuesday        NaN
3     NaN      NaN        NaN

print (df.replace('None', np.nan).bfill(axis=1))
    Monday  Tuesday Wednesday
0   Monday      NaN       NaN
1      NaN      NaN       NaN
2  Tuesday  Tuesday       NaN
3      NaN      NaN       NaN

print (df.replace('None', np.nan).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0])
0     Monday
1        NaN
2    Tuesday
3        NaN
Name: Monday, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, that does accomplish what I needed. Can you share some details on what the code is doing at .bfill and onward?

Answer (score 2):

The max function can help you here, but you need to temporarily replace the 'None' text with '0', like so.

```
df['newcolumn'] = df.replace('None', '0').max(axis=1).replace('0', 'None')
```

Answer (score -1):

**A less elegant way of approaching:**
Iterate over rows, using logic (or comparisons) to find the day per row. Append to a list and then add to the dataframe.

```
# Initialize empty list
Days = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
  # assume there is no day
  day = None
  for col in ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday']:
    # if there is a value, set value to day
    if str(row[col])!='None':
      day = row[col]
  # append to list
  Days.append(day)

# Add list to df
df['Day'] = Days

# Drop unused cols

df.drop(columns = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday'], inplace = True)
print(df)
       Day
0   Monday
1     None
2  Tuesday
```